# How do I count the number of words in a text file using C?

Tags: c, word-count

I need some help with a program that I am writing for my Systems Programming class.  It is in C and I have very, very little experience with C.  I need to merge three text file with the format:

```
word1
word2
word3
...
wordX
```

I am also to bring each of the words from all three files and put them into a 2D array (an array of string-arrays), then use some sort of sorting method on them.

I shouldn't need help with the sorting, but I don't know how to get the word count from each of the text files or put them into an array.

---

This is the function I have for counting the words in the file. It doesn't compile on `gcc` (probably for obvious reasons, but I don't know them).  Do I even have the right idea?

```
int countWords(FILE f){
   int count = 0;
   char ch;
   while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
       if (ch == '\n')
           count++;
       //return count; originally here, but shouldn't be.
   }
       return count;
}
```

---

EDIT: I supposed I could just find a way to count the lines in the program, but I'm not sure if the approach would be any different from what I am trying to do here.  (I have never really been that good at working with text files.

---

I got it to count all of the lines in the program.  I guess I'm a little rusty.

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int countWords(FILE *f){
   int count = 0;
   char ch;
   while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
       if (ch == '\n')
           count++;
   }
   return count;
}
int main(void){

   int wordCount = 0;
   FILE *rFile = fopen("american0.txt", "r");
   wordCount += countWords(rFile);
   printf("%d", wordCount);
   return 0;
}
```

---

I kind of forgot about that the pointer thing with `FILE *fileName`

Comment: Can you post the compiler error messages that you're getting?

Comment: So, given that each word is on a different line, you *really* want to count the lines: correct?

Comment: HW3.c: In function âcountWordsâ:
HW3.c:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of âfgetcâ
HW3.c: In function âmainâ:
HW3.c:19: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of âcountWordsâ
HW3.c:21:3: warning: no newline at end of file

Comment: Yeah I could just count the lines

Comment: I removed the space between each line because from your comment (which I also removed) I gathered you didn't want them there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you use for a file in c is `FILE*`. That star is important, indicating that the type is a "pointer to FILE". It is unlikely that `countWords(FILE f)` is what you meant to write.

Each time you call your function, it will have a fresh `count = 0`, so it will always return 0 or 1. Try using `static int count;`, making count a global variable, or passing in the current count to the function. Your other option is to move the `return count;` line outside of the `while` loop.

You will also probably need to divide the count by two to get the number of words, using the format you posted.

Comment: Why would OP need to divide the count by two?

Comment: oops.  The return statement should be outside the while loop.  That function just counts the number of new line statements in the file.  There is a different counting variable in the main function.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: When I wrote that, the format the OP posted had "word1\n\nword2\n\n..."

Comment: @Borealid - I remember that, but it also said (I checked the revision history) "(without the extra line between the words, I am new at this)".

Answer (score 2):

It should be `int countWords(FILE *f){`, with `*`. And the `return` statement should go before the last `}` only, outside the loop.

Comment: ok, but apart from that. Is there anything else that looks potentially deadly?

Comment: That function looks ok with those changes. I don't know about the rest of it, it doesn't seem well-specified to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Just read the number of spaces, that it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define FILE_READ "file.txt"

    int main()

{
    FILE * filp;
    int count = 1;
    char c;
    filp = fopen(FILE_READ, "r");
    if(filp == NULL)
        printf("file not found\n");
    while((c = fgetc(filp)) != EOF) {
        if(c == ' ')
            count++;
    }
    printf("worrds = %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

text file

```
I am megharaj, from india.
```

output,

```
worrds = 5
```

Comment: Any idea how i can count number of lines in a txt file ??

Comment: if(c == ' ') replace with if(c == '\n')

Comment: @Megharaj  If file contains only space this program counts them as word, but it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

here's a code from my uni book

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  int count = 0, word=0;
  char ch;

  while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
      word = 0;
      } else {
        if(!word){
          count++;
          word = 1;
        }
      }
   }

  printf("%d", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, use code in addition to explanations