# How do i copy text from file to array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Im trying to write a function that, given a filename will read strings from the file to an array of strings. This array (list) will then be returned by the function.

I've tried list being of type char * as well as an array of [50][100] where 50 is the maximum number of words in a list and 100 is the maximum length of a word. I've also tried both copying the word to an index in the array using strcpy and setting an index in the list to word (list[i] = word).

```
char list[100][100];
char word[100];
int i = 0;
FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r+");

while (!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
    strcpy(list[i], word);
    i++;
}
```

When i run code that calls this function (and no other function) I get a segmentation fault 11.

---

EDIT: I have changed the code to run as below:

```
char arr[100][100];

    int i = 0;

    FILE * fp = fopen("collection.txt", "r+");
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", arr[i]) == 1 && i < 100) {
        i++;
    }
```

It works when i test it in a main function however I can't get it to work when calling it as a function. I had defined the function as:

```
char get_list (char * filename);
```

and called this function from a main function using

```
char list = get_list ("testfile.txt");
```

and the compiler is giving warning:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'char [100][100]' from a function with result type 'char' [-Wint-conversion]
```

How should this function be defined and called?

Comment: You're loop is bounded only by an erroneous `while (!feof(fp))`, which in itself is wrong.Read this: [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong). Second, don't let more than 100 strings come through or you're going to breach your array and invoke undefined behavior. Third, make sure any string you're reading fits in `word` (a 100 character string or larger will *not*, accounting for the terminator). And after all of that, `word` is useless; you can read directly into `list[i]` and avoid the `strcpy` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your array (list) to something else. And tell us what happens

Note: Add an extra condition in the while loop `&& i < 100`

**This works for me**

```
char arr[100][100];
char word[100];
int i = 0;

FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
while (!feof(fp) && i < 100)
    fscanf(fp, "%s", arr[i++]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is your array defined 'list' is out of bound. Because the text file may contain Char(in this code,word) **more than 100**. Try to add another condition to avoid that, just like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char list[100][100];
    char word[100];
    int i = 0;
    char filename[]="mytxt.txt";
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r+");



    while (!feof(fp) && i<100 )
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
        strcpy(list[i], word);
        i++;
    }

    printf(list[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

or you can modify that code to get the char length of the text file and looping that.

Comment: check this code if you want to modify yours  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374062/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-text-file-using-c

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Whenever you are reading data in a loop, you control the loop with the read function, e.g.

```
#define ROWS 100    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS
...
    /* you control the read loop with the read function itself
     * you must protect your ROW bounds with the counter and 
     * protect your COL bounds with the field-width modifier.
     */
    while (i < ROWS && fscanf (fp, "%99s", list[i]) == 1)
        i++;                        /* increment counter */
```

Above you protect your `ROWS` (rows) array bound by only adding a new word while your counter is less than the number of rows available. You protect your `COLS` bound by using the *field-width* modifier to the `"%s"` *conversion specifier* to ensure no more than `99` characters are read into your array (saving room for +1 -- the *nul-terminating* character).

(**note:** your `words` array was superfluous. You can read directly into `list`)

You now have all words read from the file stored in list. It doesn't matter whether there are one or more words on each line, you read a word-at-a-time and the `"%s"` conversion specifier ignores leading whitespace (including `'\n'`).

A short example that reads words from the file provided as the first argument to your program (or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument was given) could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 100    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char list[ROWS][COLS];  /* 2D array to hold strings (words) */
    int i = 0;              /* counter for strings */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* you control the read loop with the read function itself
     * you must protect your ROW bounds with the counter and 
     * protect your COL bounds with the field-width modifier.
     */
    while (i < ROWS && fscanf (fp, "%99s", list[i]) == 1)
        i++;                        /* increment counter */

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)     /* output stored words */
        printf ("list[%2d] : %s\n", j, list[j]);

    if (fp != stdin)                /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File**

Taking a file with multiple words on some lines and a single word on others:

```
$ cat dat/dictwrds20.txt
a
AAA
AAAS
aardvark Aarhus Aaron ABA
Ababa
aback
abacus abalone abandon abase
abash
abate abbas abbe
abbey
abbot
Abbott
```

**Example Use/Output**

The code above reads each word into your `list` array without any problems:

```
$ ./bin/readlist dat/dictwrds20.txt
list[ 0] : a
list[ 1] : AAA
list[ 2] : AAAS
list[ 3] : aardvark
list[ 4] : Aarhus
list[ 5] : Aaron
list[ 6] : ABA
list[ 7] : Ababa
list[ 8] : aback
list[ 9] : abacus
list[10] : abalone
list[11] : abandon
list[12] : abase
list[13] : abash
list[14] : abate
list[15] : abbas
list[16] : abbe
list[17] : abbey
list[18] : abbot
list[19] : Abbott
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.